# Is there a formal way to describe classical logic as a reflective subcategory of constructive logic?

Tags: logic, category-theory, constructive-mathematics

Working informally, we can take any proof $P$ in constructive (or intuitionistic) logic and turn it into a classical proof $cP$ by 'copying' it, since all the rules of constructive logic reappear in classical logic. For a classical proof $Q$ of $q$, we can form the [double negation translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) $Q^N$, a constructive proof of $\lnot \lnot q$. Double negation translation followed by copying sends a classical proof to an equivalent classical proof. The other way around, copying followed by double negation, sends a constructive proof $P$ of $p$ to $(cP)^N$, which is syntactically equal to $P^N$, a proof of $\lnot \lnot p$. Since $p \rightarrow \lnot \lnot p$, it seems we have an 'adjunction' $c \dashv -^N$, which means we could classical logic a 'reflective subsomething' of constructive logic.

Can these ideas be formalized? That is, are there categories $\textbf{Clas}  \stackrel{\stackrel{}{\leftarrow}}{\hookrightarrow} \textbf{Cons}$ defined in ways reasonably similar to the intuitions above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to formalize the idea is to say the following: the category of classical propositional theories is a reflective subcategory of the category of intuitionistic propositional theories.  In order to make sense of that claim, it's best to pass from "theories" to "algebras."  Each classical theory corresponds to a Boolean algebra, and each intuitionistic theory corresponds to a Heyting algebra.  The category of classical propositional theories is really just the category $\mathbf{BOOL}$ of Boolean algebras; and the category of intuitionistic propositional theories is really just the category $\mathbf{HEYT}$ of Heyting algebras.

[For a theory $T$, let $B_T$ be the Boolean algebra whose elements are equivalence classes of sentences modulo $T$-provable equivalence.  Alternatively, we could build a Heyting algebra $H_T$ from $T$ using the same procedure, but using intuitionistic logic for provable equivalence.  It's not difficult to see that, in fact, every Boolean algebra is a Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra for some theory.  Similarly, every Heyting algebra results from some theory.  So we might as well use Boolean and Heyting algebras in the place of theories.]

Obviously there is an inclusion $I:\mathbf{BOOL}\to\mathbf{HEYT}$.  The double-negation translation $F:\mathbf{HEYT}\to\mathbf{BOOL}$ is the left adjoint to $I$.  For more information, see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra

Comment: This appears to be the right way of understanding the relationship at the level of propositional logic (+1), but what about full blown first-order logic?

Comment: One way to understand the relationship at the level of first-order logic is to use of topos theory.  Here intuitionistic theories correspond to a certain sort of  topos, and classical theories correspond to a certain sort of Boolean topos.  It is well known that the double-negation translation extends to toposes.  I suspect that the category of classical theories is a reflective subcategory of the category intuitionistic theories, but I haven't seen a proof of this fact.